# Vagrant HTTP 500 error

Tags: php, vagrant, vagrantfile, http-status-code-500

I'm currently working on project using Vagrant and I'm using [Scotch Box 2.5](https://box.scotch.io/). The setting up part was very successful even in SSH, I installed Apache and PHP 5.6. When I tried accessing to my site, it said **HTTP 500 error**.
I also use VirtualHost (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RoverWire/virtualhost/master/virtualhost.sh) and this is my Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

# Optional NFS. Make sure to remove other synced_folder line too
#config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] }

end
```

Any idea how to fix this problem? Thank you.

*note: The Virtual Host points to the Document Root folder (var/www/).